zfs: Destroying snapshot frees way more than expected
Before:
$ zfs list -t snapshot -r rpool/DATA 
NAME                                                USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool/DATA@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2023-10-01-0452    140G      -  22.7T  -
rpool/DATA@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2023-11-01-0552    117G      -  23.1T  -
rpool/DATA@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2023-12-01-0552   12.0G      -  24.2T  -
rpool/DATA@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2024-01-01-0552   19.5G      -  18.7T  -
:
[...more snapshots...]
$ df
Filesystem       1K-blocks        Used  Available Use% Mounted on                             
rpool/DATA     20072349312 18735674368 1336674944  94% /data

I then deleted the three oldest snapshots:
sudo zfs destroy rpool/DATA@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2023-10-01-0452
sudo zfs destroy rpool/DATA@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2023-11-01-0552
sudo zfs destroy rpool/DATA@zfs-auto-snap_monthly-2023-12-01-0552

I had expected to free up: 140G+117G+12.0G = 269 GB
But I get:
$ df /data
Filesystem       1K-blocks        Used  Available Use% Mounted on
rpool/DATA     27269808768 18732491136 8537317632  69% /data

Clearly my prediction was wrong: 7TB instead of 0.3TB
How do I predict how much space I will reclaim by destroying a snapshot?

You've added up the deltas from one to the next, but you've overlooked the fact that the 2024-01-01 snapshot, while using 19.5 G more data than the previous snap, references roughly 5.5 T less data than the previous snaps.  I don't know all the internal math, but I would speculate that the 01-01 snapshot has 19.5 G of new or modified data, along with a significant drop from data having been rm-ed, truncated, or otherwise deleted.  In short, that's why you're off by so much.
Indeed, when culling old backups manually, I often look for a transition where the REFER column drops appreciably, and if that is a reasonable date frame, I am likely to consider deleting the snapshots prior to that drop.
You may also find handy an alias I use:
alias zls='zfs list -o name,used,usedsnap -s usedsnap'

This doesn't perform any sort of the above analysis of the REFER value, but it does clue you in to which filesystems have the most data tied up in snapshots (i.e., non-current data).  That helps guide me to where the biggest gains can be made as I begin my REFER analysis.
Without args, it looks at all filesystems on all pools:
$ zls
NAME                 USED  USEDSNAP
tank                1.79T        0B
tank/ROOT           12.3G        0B
tank/usr            5.92G        0B
tank/usr/obj        2.33G        0B
tank/usr/src        3.59G        0B
tank/var             282M        0B
tank/jail           18.6G     1.52M
tank/var/tmp        2.67M     2.54M
tank/tmp             112M     89.0M
tank/var/log         279M      276M
tank/ROOT/default   12.3G     10.5G
tank/jail/hostname  18.6G     15.5G
tank/data           1.75T     1.02T

Additional zfs list options or pools/filesystems can be appended, with varying degrees of accuracy:
$ zls -d1   (not accurate)
NAME        USED  USEDSNAP
tank       1.79T        0B
tank/ROOT  12.3G        0B
tank/usr   5.92G        0B
tank/var    282M        0B
tank/jail  18.6G     1.52M
tank/tmp    112M     89.0M
tank/data  1.75T     1.02T

$ zls -r tank/ROOT tank/data   # multiple filesystems
NAME                USED  USEDSNAP
tank/ROOT          12.3G        0B
tank/ROOT/default  12.3G     10.5G
tank/data          1.75T     1.02T

$ zls -r tank1   # display tank1 but not tank2 or tank3

... etc.

I still cannot get the math to add up. How does the 5.5 suddenly become 7? It is not just a rounding error. I might understand 5.8 given that I removed 0.3TB of data used.

@OleTange First, I wouldn't trust df. But as I said in my post, I don't know, I just wanted to direct you toward the major source of your discrepancy. In general, a good question for Matt Ahrens. A more experienced user than I might be able to suggest tools like zdb and others which will help you find both similarities and differences between snapshots of a given dataset.

zdb seems to be an awful big gun to use for something that to me seems a pretty normal use: Decide if you are going to destroy a snapshot to free some disk space. But I interpret your answer as you also do not have a good tool to make the decision - only rules of thumb.

@OleTange I'm open to any new tools, but zfs diff seems woefully underpowered.  More to the point, I don't worry about how MUCH backup data I'm deleting; my concern is usually how OLD.  I like to keep a certain amount of historical data, but I count it in days, not bytes. For that analysis, zfs list is a perfectly good tool for making the decision.  Can you edit your post to explain why are you concerned about freeing "too much" space?  If the snaps are so old they're of little value, who cares how large they are?  Indeed, if obsolete backups ARE large, all the better to delete them!

I would prefer 1 yr of backup, but I am not going to upgrade the system, if I can have 9 months. And since I could see the disk running full (94%) and I needed the 0.3 TB extra for this night's backup, I wanted to free up 0.3 TB. In retrospect I should simply have deleted the oldest and the seen how much would be free, but I naively assumed the numbers were reliable. Which is why I am asking: How should I have done to get reliable numbers?
